# Company Completion Within Yasnippet Snippet

Tags: completion, company-mode, yasnippet

I am trying to use company-completion within a Yasnippet header. I bound company-complete to C-SPC and use that for my auto-completion. When I hit control enter, I get a screen like this:
[image]

And I hit enter to get this:

[image]

Then I start typing iost- and wait to get the company-complete (It breaks immediately when I hit C-SPC, see below):

[image]

And then I hit enter to complete, and this happens: (or immediately if I hit C-SPC):

[image]

I tried googling around but no solution worked. I only want to be able to yasnippet snippets from the company-complete dropdown if that's possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you would find my answer http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7925/5368 to another question useful. I use tab as my binding for both company and yasnippet, but probably it can be adapted to C-space...

Comment: Thank you kristof! That seems to work very well. I still get this bug on the header files but it works fine everywhere else. Thank you!

Comment: You could try reporting that bug on Company's [issue tracker](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues).

Comment: @davess You really should report this to the issue tracker, but please include the minimal necessary configuration to reproduce the problem.