# disable TAB in company-mode

Tags: key-bindings, company-mode, yasnippet

I'm trying to get several plugins all playing nicely: yasnippet, company-mode and ENSIME.

I'm aware of [How to make yasnippet and company work nicer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7908) but I was thinking about another, simpler, approach: can I just disable company-mode's TAB altogether?

I use `RET` to expand completions and I very rarely want to use `TAB` to select the maximum common matching expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `C-h M-k` (`describe-keymap`) from [`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus) to find out what command `company-mode-map` (or whatever the mode's keymap is called) binds to `TAB`.

Then do `(define-key company-mode-map THE-COMMAND nil)`, where `THE-COMMAND` is that command, to unbind it. (Or use another key sequence in place of `nil`, to bind it to a different key.)

---

UPDATE by @fommil:

You'll find that the following will then unbind `TAB`

```
(define-key company-active-map 'company-complete-common nil)
```

Comment: `(define-key company-active-map 'company-complete-common nil)` :smile: